# Do we always need a separate runner class for cucumber tests?

Tags: cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

Almost every reference in the web for cucumber project has a separate runner class with nothing in class body. Seems like a waste of class.
My case, the following is the project skeleton

RestTestContext.java

```
public class RestTestContext {
private Map<String, String>           restParams    = new HashMap<>();

public void setRestParams(Map<String, String> params) {
       this.restParams.putAll(params);
    }

public Map<String, String> getRestParams() {
        return this.restParams;
    }
}
```

Next I have the `StepDefinitions.Java`
And a 
TestRunner.Java having,

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/resources/features/"},
            tags = {"@run"},
            dryRun = false,
            monochrome = true
        )

public class TestRunner{

}
```

This works totally fine, of course.

Now I could also do the same thing by modifying the `RestTestContext.java`as below

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/resources/features/"},
            tags = {"@run"},
            dryRun = false,
            monochrome = true
        )

public class RestTestContext {
private Map<String, String>           restParams    = new HashMap<>();

public void setRestParams(Map<String, String> params) {
       this.restParams.putAll(params);
    }

public Map<String, String> getRestParams() {
        return this.restParams;
    }
}
```

This makes me not to have an empty class just to notify JUnit on how to run. But to have some useful class body as well.

The question: Is it just a best practice to have a separate runner class? Or does it contribute to other factors as well?

Comment: [The Single Responsibility Principle](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/solid-part-1-the-single-responsibility-principle--net-36074)

Answer (score 1):

Afaik if you want to run your Cucumber tests with JUnit, you'll need a runner class. You can check the [documentation](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/api/#junit) for more information.
Note that you are also using this class to specify your `@CucumberOptions`, telling Cucumber & JUnit *how* to run your tests.

Note that you can also run Cucumber from the [command line](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/api/#from-the-command-line). In that case you will not be using JUnit.

Finally, you can also run your tests from your IDE. How to do so, will depend on which IDE you are using. You can find some info on Java IDE's in the [documentation](https://docs.cucumber.io/tools/java/#ides).